# WordPress İmages Upload & Delete Error

Tags: php, images, uploads

i get this error when i am making a list in the admin panel for the codes beneath
i will send a screenshot of the error
[image]
i need to do the deleting operation apart from listing, im waiting for your help

```
function aksesuar_resim_deletes()

{

    $directory = get_home_path(). '/wp-content/aksesuar/';
    $files = glob($directory .'*');

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) ) $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] = false;


    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon(); echo "<h2>". __( 'Resim Silme Servisi', 'aksesuar_resim_deletes' ) . "</h2>"; ?>
        <?php if ( false !== $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) : ?>
            <p><strong><?php _e( 'Options saved', 'aksesuar_resim_deletes' ); ?></strong></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <?php settings_fields( 'aksesuar_resim_uploads' ); ?>
            <?php $options = get_option( 'aksesuar_resim_uploads' ); ?>
            <div id="wp-theme-file-uploader">
                <p>
                    <label for="folders">Resim Klasörü Seç:</label>
                    <select name="folder">
                        <?php foreach($files as $file): ?>
                            <?php if(is_dir($file)): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo basename($file); ?>"><?php echo basename($file); ?></option>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Resimleri getir">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php
    $imageFiles = array();
    $extensions = array('.JPG','.PNG','.JPEG');
    $dir =home_url().'/wp-content/aksesuar/'.$_POST['folder'];
    $openDir = opendir($dir);

    while ($imgFile = readdir($openDir))
    {
        if ($imgFile <> '.' and $imgFile <> '..')
        {
            $extension = strtoupper(substr($imgFile, strrpos($imgFile, '.')));
            if (in_array($extension, $extensions))
            {
                $imageFiles[] = $imgFile;
            }
        }
    }

    closedir($openDir);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($imageFiles as $k => $v)
    {

        echo '<li style="float: left;padding-right: 10px;"><img src="'.$dir.'/'.$v.'" width="238" height="238" alt=""/></li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`opendir` operates on directories on a filesystem, not HTTP URIs.

While some HTTP URIs return directory listings (the one you are using doesn't, it is a 404 error), those listings as HTML documents generated by the webserver and are not actual directories.

So please change value of `$directory` variable.

For Example:

Current value in `$directory = "http:/localhost/WP/wp-content";`

Need to be correct like : `$directory ='<wwwroot>/WP/wp-content';`

**NOTE:** `[opendir()][1]` is used to open a local directory and since PHP 5.0.0 on an ftp directory.